# UITableView disappeared when reloadData

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, animation, frame

I have a `UIScrollView` with some elements inside. One of them is a `UITableView`. I need to hide this table view, reload its contents and show again but when I make `[self.tableView reloadData];` the table never appears, it still hide.

```
- (void)hideTableMotivesAndReloadData
{
    NSLog(@"Hiding table and reloading data");

    // Hiding tableView
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.tableMotives.alpha = 0;
        self.textComments.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [self.tableMotives reloadData];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:1.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
        animations:^{
            self.tableMotives.alpha = 1;
            self.textComments.alpha = 1;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            //
        }];

    }];
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

**Edited:**

I added a `NSLog(self.tableMotives.description)` before and after `reloadData` call, it is the result:

Before:

```
<UITableView: 0x1529bc00; frame = (-1 789; 770 420); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x14d73960>; layer = <CALayer: 0x14d9a5c0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
```

After:

```
<UITableView: 0x1529bc00; frame = (-1 344; 770 81); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x14d73960>; layer = <CALayer: 0x14d9a5c0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
```

I change the frame manually in the second Completion block adding this:

```
CGRect frame = self.tableMotives.frame;
frame.origin.y = 1000;
frame.size.height = 800;
[self.tableMotives setFrame:frame];
```

And the table appeared...

**Edited:**

Thanks guys, before tried your suggestions I found that when `reloadData` is called the `tableView` is re-ubicated to the `StoryBoard` original position. Seems that lost his frame and get the frame specified in `storyboard`. Somebody understand it?

Comment: Did you try set alpha to 1.0f instead of 1?

Comment: hello, yes i,ve tried. Only not show the table when i call reloadData

Comment: You're saying that if you take out the reloadData call, it works as expected? Are you sure that the table view is actually hidden, and not just empty?

Comment: Ian, yes, works when I take out reloadData and after it still having data.

Comment: Have you tried moving the `reloadData` call to the second completion block?

Comment: Neilco, I've tried. Still not working. It's very strange, every time  that I call reloadData, the tableView disappears

Comment: Are you sure there is content in the tableview after reload?

Comment: Adithya, the content is there. I updated my question. The tableview is here but it reset itself to storyboard position when I call reloadData

Answer (score 0):

try hidden property of tableview

```
[self.tableMotives setHidden:YES];
```

and set hidden to no after reload

```
[self.tableMotives setHidden:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)hideTableMotivesAndReloadData
{
NSLog(@"Hiding table and reloading data");

// Hiding tableView
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.tableMotives.alpha = 0;
    self.textComments.alpha = 0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:1.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
    animations:^{
        self.tableMotives.alpha = 1;
        self.textComments.alpha = 1;
        [self.tableMotives reloadData];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        //
    }];
}];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adithya, same result :( I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked for me.

Hope it helps... :)

```
- (void)hideTableMotivesAndReloadData
{
    NSLog(@"Hiding table and reloading data");

    // Hiding tableView
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self. tableMotives.alpha = 0;
    self.textComments.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.tableMotives reloadData];
    }];
}

- (void)showTableMotives{
    NSLog(@"Showing table and reloading data");

    // Showing tableView
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
        self.tableMotives.alpha = 1;
        self.textComments.alpha = 1;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Some other code if needed
    if([indexPath row] == ((NSIndexPath*)[[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] lastObject]).row){
        //end of loading
        [self showTableMotives];
    }
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 24;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %d", indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks amanhuipg but still not working. I think that i have a clue I updated my question.